# Python script not running in visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to run some python(v=3.11) scripts using visual studio code(v=1.73.1) but doesn't matter what the code is (even just a simple "hello world"). When I type the name of the script in the terminal I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\biagini.WISMAIN\Desktop\PhD project\Python course\Tommaso Biagini_v2> hello.py
hello.py : The term 'hello.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ hello.py
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hello.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command hello.py was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\hello.py". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

I have tried to follow the suggestion but it still doesn't run.

Also what is weird visual studio was working perfectly fine unntill few days ago and now it suddently started to give me this error. Can someone please help me?

I have already tried the suggestion promped by the terminal but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You need a Python interpreter to run your code. Try `python hello.py` if your python interpreter is installed in your environment.

Comment: I did it! That is working but still, if I just type in the name of the script, giving me the same error. How can I change it?

Comment: @TommasoBiagini You cannot run python files like that. The only file type that is run like that are executable files (like .exe in windows, and running is done by .\filename.exe). If you want to have an executable file of your final product, you can search on Google by something like this "python project to executable". But during the development I wouldn't suggest creating an executable file.

Comment: @TommasoBiagini Another alternative approach to run your python files might be using the interface of VS Code instead of using the terminal, if that will be easier for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I still don't understand though why I was able to run the scripts without the need of typing "python" before. Do you have any idea about that?